# Wordpress - line break after first word in title

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

So I kind of have this working however it's outputting wrong.

E.G. I have 3 pages which are being queried through a loop.

1. Chesty Coughs
2. Chocolate Buttons
3. Dairy Milk

I'd like them to look like this:

Chesty

Coughs (with a br after the first word)

This is what I've managed so far and it seems to work:

```
$tit = get_the_title();
$parts = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $tit); 
foreach($parts as $part) { 
    preg_match_all('/\S+\S+/', $part, $names); 
    foreach($names[0] as $name) { 
        $separate.= "$name<br/>"; 
    } 
}
```

HOWEVER after each post the last title seems to get added onto the one before

E.G.
< - - - firstpost - - - >

Chesty
Coughs

< - - - next post - - - >

Chesty
Coughs
Chocolate 
Buttons

< - - - next post - - - >

Chesty
Coughs
Chocolate 
Buttons
Dairy
Milk

This is my entire loop:

```
 $args = array(
 'post_type' => 'page',
 'post_status' => 'publish',
 'meta_query' => array(
  array(
   'key' => '_wp_page_template',
   'value' => 'template-name.php' // template name as stored in the dB
    )
 )
 );
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
// The Loop
if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {                        
   while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        $my_query->the_post();      

        $tit = get_the_title();
        $parts = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $tit); 
        foreach($parts as $part) { 
            preg_match_all('/\S+\S+/', $part, $names); 
            foreach($names[0] as $name) { 
                $separate.= "$name<br/>"; 
            } 
        }
        echo '<h3>'.$separate.'</h3>';
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

How would I fix it so it outputs correctly?

Comment: you need to insert somewhere $separate = "" to clean it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Way too complicated. You're seeing titles concatenated because you're telling it to with `.=`. There's no need to do it that way. Instead, just replace the `' '` (space) string with a `'\n'` newline or `'<br>'`.

```
if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {                        
   while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        $my_query->the_post();      

        $title = get_the_title();
        echo '<h3>' . str_replace(" ", "<br>", $title) . '</h3>';
    }
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Thank you - that does look a lot simpler! :)